# Why are Javascript libraries like LoDash or UnderScore utilized more often than raw JS functions like map, reduce, or filter

Tags: javascript, dictionary, underscore.js, reduce, lodash

I tend to find the listed libraries utilized more often when straight JS functions would have done the job. I would believe that loading additional libraries would always add more load time, so I am curious as to why raw JS functions are not used more often.

Are there any speed advantages to just pure JS functions in the language over post-written helper functions?

Wouldn't the benefit of the pre-made library be lost on the additional library load times?

Comment: Yes raw functions do a lot, but they do enough. So you need to use these libs or just write the while code yourself again and again. And once you are uwing something, then atick to it to keep the flow. It sometimes create uneeded problems when you are mixing native and these utilities lib. Like no chaining. You make less errors and use documentation from one place.

Comment: If you looked at Underscore, you'd see that map, reduce and filter are about 2% of its functionality. People use it for the other 98%.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the use of a framework over raw JS is the compatibility.  There are differences in Javascript between browsers, between different versions of browsers, and some implementations are incomplete.  A tool like underscore and the like helps to smoothen out problems with compatibility providing a common layer between your code and raw JS.

If you can eliminate the possiblity of having different browsers then sure, go ahead and do Raw JS, but in the long run you save yourself the extra hassle down the road.

Comment: Can you point out a specific case where Underscore papers over differences between browsers?

Comment: If you look at the source code of underscore, there are a few variables `var
    nativeIsArray = Array.isArray,
    nativeKeys = Object.keys,
    nativeCreate = Object.create;` which are used later to determine if the function exists already then use it otherwise it defines a new function.  There are other examples but those are the most straight forward ones..

Answer (score 3):

The three main reasons I turn to lodash...

### Functionality

Yes, there's some overlap between what JavaScript primitives can do, and what lodash can do. For myself at least, it's not just a matter of which implementation of `map()` is better, or which implementation of `reduce()` is better, and so on. If all you're doing is mapping and reducing, then lodash is of little value.

If your building a medium-to-large sized application on the other hand, you're probably doing a lot more with your data. This is an area lodash shines. It gives me everything I need, in an a very granular form. The granularity matters because it means I can choose and combine the parts I need. I could do a lot of in myself using native methods, but why do that when the code is already written for me?

### Performance

Lodash performs well. Maybe as well as the browser primitives, or in some cases better. It doesn't matter, the performance gains are negligible for simple comparisons.

The big performance wins come not from micro-benchmarking, but in real-world implementations, where there's a lot of code, and a lot of data. The lodash performance mantra is *optimize for the common case*. Lodash does this all over the place.

For example, the more common, more performant path, is checked *first* in any given function. The slow paths are pushed to the bottom of the function. They can afford to be slow, because they're uncommon. These checks have a huge cumulative effect in real applications.

I find lodash performance to be consistent when I'm operating on collections because it uses the same iteration techniques for all the functions that involve iterating over a collection. So I'm not worried about one function being inherently slower than another function because it does things differently. The differences are minute, and the so are the performance characteristics.

Lodash also considers the JIT of the JavaScript engine, and takes steps in making sure it's internal functions don't incur optimization penalties.

John-David Dalton has a great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD9utLH3QOk) on lodash performance.

### Better code

Because of all the exposed functionality, I'm constantly finding ways to improve my code. Often ripping out function calls, and replacing them with a different strategy that uses less code.

I find that lodash, especially chained calls, make it easy to improve existing code. If I have to write all these utilities myself, it's not likely to be as elegant as the lodash version.

The granularity of the lodash API forces me to re-think everything I'm doing, as I'm doing it, and it's quite enjoyable.